# Что такое «игра на обострение»?

Tags: значения

Это выражение почему-то часто слышится у политиков. Что это за игра?)

Answer (score 2):

**"Игра на обострение"** - это то, что иначе называют **"повышать ставки"** (**raise the stakes**), т.е. превращение вялотекущей игры, когда от результата очередного раунда почти ничего не зависит, в острую фазу, когда ставки максимально высоки и за один раз можно выиграть или потерять всё.

Comment: “Bet one’s bottom dollar on...”?

Comment: @ВикторСун, "Put everything on the line"

Answer (score 0):

Это сказал Владимир Путин о провокационных действиях Украины в Керченском проливе. И он это сам же и объяснил в своей речи:

> "Это провокация, которая организована действующей властью в преддверие
>   президентских выборов на Украине в марте следующего года. Рейтинг
>   действующего президента находится на пятой строчке, у него есть шансы
>   не войти даже во второй тур, и поэтому нужно что-то делать, чтобы
>   ситуацию обострить и создать непреодолимые препятствия для его
>   конкурентов, прежде всего, из оппозиции."

То есть, Путин имеет в виду, что действия противоположной стороны конфликта были намеренными, вызванными не необходимостью обороны, а политической игрой, направленной на обострение конфликта и получение выгоды от него.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86436/discussion-on-answer-by-elena-----).